How to use custom JWT Authentication in .NET 8 Blazor App with Auto Render Mode
when I create a Blazor application it generates server and client application. I am creating Api's in the server side of the application. So when app is render it is render in server mode and my pages are rendered form the clinet. i have created a custom AuthenticationStateProvider and register it on both server and client side.
The Problem is I need to store the token somewhere, which should be accessible form the server and client.
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["token"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            return new AuthenticationState(_anonymous);

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token).Claims, "jwt");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }

    public void UpdateAuthenticationState(string token)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("token");
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous)));
            return;
        }

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token).Claims, "jwt");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            Secure = true
        };
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", token, cookieOptions);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
    }
}

When using httpContextAccessor client don't have this object.
Error  blazor.web.js:1  Error: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Client.CustomAuthenticationStateProvider'.)
when using Local storage or session storage Server gives error with JSRuntime interpole

You talk about transition from Server to WASM, but you may mean transition from pre-render.  If so, then read this Microsoft document  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state

No I am not trying this. i need to maintain my auth state form server app and client app using same custom auth provider.

Ihttpcontextaccessor only available for ServerinterActive and SSR, not for WASM.

You can only use httpcontext.response.cookie in SSR mode. During "ServerSignalR" and "WASM", you cannot use it, you have to use Js interop to operate the cookie in the browser (To determine the rendermode, see my this answer: How can I programmatically determine the Blazor render mode). I have tested following code and works well.
First, Add following js script at the bottom of App.razor
<script>

    function test() {
        console.log("test");
    }

    function WriteCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires;
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else {
            expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function ReadCookie(name) {
        console.log("test");
        const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
        const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
        if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }

</script>

Then after determine to rendermode, you could choose to use httpcontext or  jsinterop to set/read cookie.
    public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IJSRuntime js;

        public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IJSRuntime js)
        {
            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            this.js = js;
        }

        public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            string token = "";
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
            {
                if (!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
                {

                    token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["token"];
                }
                else
                {
                    //js.InvokeVoidAsync("test");
                    token =await js.InvokeAsync<string>("ReadCookie", "token");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                token= await js.InvokeAsync<string>("ReadCookie", "token");
            }


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            }

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token).Claims, "jwt");
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(identity)));

        }

        public async Task Update(string token)
        {
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
            {
                if (!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
                {

                    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", token);
                }
                else
                {
                     await js.InvokeVoidAsync("WriteCookie", "token", token, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await js.InvokeVoidAsync("WriteCookie", "token", token, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));

            }


            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token).Claims, "jwt");
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity))));
        }
    }

